How to judge if some prediction results are good in this particular case
I would like some advice on my particular case.
I have some script that analyze some Ground truth and some prediction results on object detection.
The results from the analysis is a csv file of this form
file_name,categories_found,categories_not_found
000001_1616005007200.jpg,,bollard
000001_1616005254200.jpg,,"traffic_cone, bollard"
000002_1616005443000.jpg,,"traffic_cone, debris"
000002_1616005519499.jpg,,"traffic_cone, traffic_sign, machinery, debris, misc"
000002_1616005678500.jpg,car,bollard
000003_1616006878800.jpg,barrier,

So you can see that the system could not find the bollard on the first image, etc. On the last image it could find the barrier and in the previous one it could find the car but not the bollard.
I really don't see how can I apply precision or recall or such here. So based on the info of this csv, how can I produce some judgment on how good the prediction is going?
I was thinking of just show per image how many of the categories are found and how many are not, but any other idea?
